# Updating particular field in REST call jpa

Tags: json, spring, rest, jpa, spring-boot

Am new to REST webservice, i have a scenario where each field in a form to be save to the database as when user fills the field.
So am calling an update API when user goes from one field to another. Using jpa for database operation. The problem am facing here is, lets say for example Employee.

```
{
"fname":
"lname":
"mname":
"addresses":
 {
   "line1":
   "line2":
  }
}
```

While user fills fname my json will be

```
{
"fname":"some value"
}
```

ill call rest to update. And for next field

```
{
"lname":"another value"
}
```

in this update case lname will be updated but fname updated with a blank value since am not passing fname. So i have to send full json to have a proper value.
Think if my json is too big with many relation, am feeling just to update one field its not good to pass complete json to the REST API's.

Can somebody give me any idea or any solution for this.

Am developing this with Spring-boot framework

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I tried with DTO option but that doesnt seems to be better.

Comment: Post your code here. We'll try to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Probably worth clarifying whether you're using Spring Data REST, or implementing your own API.

Comment: Am trying with my own API, but if i get answer for Spring Data REST also should be good enough